# Convergence of $\sin((n+1)\times\frac \pi 2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to find what value this series converges to without a calculator. I believe I need to convert the sin to cosine, but I'm not sure how that helps as it still leaves with the trig term alternating between $0, 1, 0,$ and $-1$. From what I read, when $n$ is even, it should be $1$, but plugging $n=2$ returns zero... is there something I'm missing?
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sin\frac{(n+1)\pi}{2}}{5^n}
$$

The correct value is $\frac{25}{26}$.

Comment: @user170231 you should write it as an answer, not in the comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $n$ is odd (so $n+1$ is even) the numerator vanishes since $\sin(n\pi)=0$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$. So one needs only consider even values of $n$; let $n=2k$, so the sum reduces to a geometric series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin\frac{(n+1)\pi}2}{5^n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\sin\frac{(2k+1)\pi}2}{5^{2k}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\sin\left(k\pi+\frac\pi2\right)}{25^k} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(-\frac1{25}\right)^k$$

where we expand

$$\sin\left(k\pi+\frac\pi2\right) = \sin(k\pi)\cos\frac\pi2 + \cos(k\pi)\sin\frac{\pi}2 = 0 + (-1)^k$$

Answer (score 2):

$n$ has been offset by $1$ in the $\sin$ function, so it actually goes $1,0,-1,0$. You can ignore the terms where $n$ is odd, so the sum can be expressed as:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{-1^n}{5^{2n}}$$
This is the same as:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{-1^n}{25^n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac1{25}\right)^n$$
The infinite geometric series formula is $\frac a{1-r}$, where $a$ is the first term and $r$ is the common ratio for the series $a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+ar^4...$ 
Plugging in the first term as $1$ and the common ratio as $-\frac1{25}$, we get:
$$\frac1{1--\frac1{25}}=\frac1{1+\frac1{25}}=\frac1{\frac{26}{25}}=\frac{25}{26}$$
That is how you get the correct answer.